# Why the size is 16 always in output in any case?

Tags: c++, oop

Here, in the output, the size of operator is coming `16`. Can anybody explain me which size is this, or why it is always `16` in any case?

I have changed the string, but still the size is `16`. I don't understand why.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class person {
    string name;
    int age;
  public:
    person() { cout << "Constructor is called\n"; }
    person(string name, int age) {
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << "Name:" << name << endl;
        cout << "Age:" << age << endl;
    }
    void *operator new(size_t size) {
        cout << "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl;
        void *a = ::new person();
        return a;
    }
    void operator delete(void *a) {
        cout << "Overloading delete operator " << endl;
        free(a);
    }
};

int main() {
    person *a = new person("avi", 20);
    a->display();
    delete a;
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: because that's how big a `string` and an `int` are?

Comment: Size of `std:string` is constant. It doesn't change with the length of string, because it allocates memory for its data on the heap.

Comment: Side note: `operator new` is a memory allocation function, and should return a pointer to memory where a new object will be created later. It should not create a new object; that object will be overwritten without being properly destroyed. If you want to just use the default allocator, write `::operator new(size);` instead of `::new person();` (and then `::operator delete(a)` to deallocate).

Comment: What are you trying to do? You're for instance combining the C++ `new` with the C `free`, which is not a good idea

Comment: It's 16 because that's what `sizeof(person)` is. Every object of given type has the same size.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be overloading `operator new`? That’s a pretty advanced feature that people can go a whole career without using.

Comment: Also, why is `person::operator new` calling `new person`? That looks rather like an infinite loop. I'm not even sure how `::new person` can compile. What's that `::` doing there? It can't be a namespace qualification, because `new` is a keyword, not a name, and keywords are not members of namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the article that you got your example from,

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-new-delete-operator-c/

> The overloaded new operator receives size of type size_t, which
> specifies the number of bytes of memory to be allocated.

In your machine [and your compiler], 16 bytes of memory should be allocated for an object of class **person**.

In my machine, 40 bytes are needed:

```
Overloading new operator with size: 40
Constructor is called
Name:avi
Age:20
Overloading delete operator 
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

When I print size of string and int, I get:

```
std::cout << "size of class person:"  << sizeof(person) << std::endl;
std::cout << "size of string:" << sizeof(string) << std::endl;
std::cout << "size of int:" <<sizeof(int) << std::endl;


size of class person:40
size of string:32
size of int:4
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

But 40 != 32 + 4
Read this article to understand why:
[here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/)

This article should help too:
https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html